# User taxonomy term with depth filter

Tags: 7, views

Please how can I filter the taxonomy depth of type user in views?

Users have taxonomy as follows:

country
-city1
-city2

The view is set up as relationship=field-country and able to create a context filter with term id.

The problem is that, although the link to the child city works fine, the link for the country doesn't work. In other words, we need a depth capability for the parent term.